# How to generate variable names

Tags: ruby

I am iterating through `this_dir`,

```
this_dir = Dir.new(".")
```

`puts`ing each .rb file. With the folders (everything that aren't .rb), I would like to open them, list their contents, and set them to a variable. I created an array `names` to get the variable name from, and planned to iterate through it by calling it with `names_index` and adding `1` to that.

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'm', 'o', 'p']
names_index = 0
```

Unfortunately, the closest thing I know how to do with Array values is `puts` them, which makes it a string.

```
this_dir.each do |file|
  if file.include?("*.rb")
    puts file
  else
    ....
  end
end
```

How do I turn the array values into variable names?

Comment: `file.include?("*.rb")` will only be true for the literal string '*.rb'. You need to put the wildcard in `Dir#glob`, as @Jordan has done. You have made no reference to `names` or `name_index` after defining those variables.

Comment: I missed how you were using `names`.

Comment: I was going to make reference to `names` and `name_index` in the spot where I substituted `....`. Unfortunately it wouldn't have had the desired behavior, so I left the dots. I wrote those two variables in my question so that my explanation would be as thorough as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `file.include?("*.rb")` will only be true for filenames that contain the literal string `'*.rb'`; that is, `'*'` does not act as a wildcard here.

Comment: Wow, heheh, nice catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to list all of the `.rb` files in a directory and its subdirectories, use `Dir.glob`  with the `**` pattern to recurse subdirectories, like so:

```
Dir.glob('./**/*.rb').each do |file|
  puts file
end
```

In general it doesn't make sense to dynamically create variable names for the purpose of storing many items. In such cases (when a better solution like `Dir.glob` above isn't available) you should just use an Array (or sometimes a Hash).

Comment: Well, this doesn't do anything with any of `/./`'s child directories, it just lists the .rb files in `/.`

I'm also interested in setting variable names in the sense that my question asked. Edit: I just re-read this an it sounded snarky; sorry about that. Any clue why it doesn't handle nested directories?

Comment: You're mistaken. The very purpose of the `**` pattern is to list files in subdirectories recursively. Take a look at the documentation for [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob). The code above will list every `.rb` file in `.` and in every subdirectory of `.` and in every subdirectory of each of those directories *ad infinitum*.

Comment: The only way to set local variables in the way you apparently want to is using `eval`, e.g. `eval("foo = 'bar'")`, but there are vanishingly few situations in which that's preferable to another method like (in the case of storing many items) an Array or Hash.

Comment: Interesting... the second time I ran code it `puts`d things exclusively in subdirectories, whereas the first time I ran code it only ran things in the `.` directory. Not quite sure why the difference, but I'm guessing the behavior on the second try was correct?

Comment: Okay, I guess your edit answers that question. Thank you so much!

Comment: As @JVernon notes, for Ruby 1.9+ you can't set local variables. One might expect `eval` or `binding.local_variable_set` would, but they don't.

Comment: Huh. Shows how often I use `eval`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Jordan already showed you a better way to achieve whatever you're apparently trying to achieve. However, if for some reason you still want to do it the way you asked, I want to point out that this used to be possible back in Ruby 1.8. But for newer versions (as of time of writing this) you can't dynamically create local variables. **But** you can still achieve something similar using a hash:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'm', 'o', 'p']
names_index = 0

table = {}

this_dir.each do |file|
  if file.include?("*.rb")
    puts file
  else
    table[names[names_index]] = file
    names_index += 1
  end
end
```

Now if a file different than `.rb` is found, it would be stored and you can access it like this:

`table['a']`

Which would return such file.

There is obviously little to no practical sense in doing this, and you should probably not do it anyway - but there it is for your curiosity.

Comment: Yeah I can see why this is not the best way to go now. The logic is pretty though... thanks for the explanation!

Comment: `"*"` in `"*.rb"` is not a wildcard. Perhaps `if file.end_with(".rb")`.